# CS0103: The name 'document' does not exist in the current context

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Sorry if it's more than once this question. But I'm trying to know why it doesn't work. Here it is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
        document.getElementById("<%= tdSiFecha.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
    }   

    function esFecha() {
        var ddl = document.getElementById("<%= cmbColumnaF1.ClientID %>");
        var nombreColumna = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
        var existe = nombreColumna.search("Fecha");
        if (existe != -1) {
            document.getElementById("<%= tdSiFecha.ClientID %>").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("<%= TDnOfECHA.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("<%= tdSiFecha.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("<%= TDnOfECHA.ClientID %>").style.display = "block";
        }

    }
</script>
```

From `esFecha` function:

```
...
<td>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="cmbColumnaF1" Style="float: left; margin-right: 5px;" runat="server" 
    Width="225px" onChange="esFecha()">
    <asp:ListItem>cmbColumna</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</td>
<td id ="tdSiFecha">
//something
</td>
<td id ="TDnOfECHA">
//something
</td>
```

On `pageLoad` function it always works after a Postback. And I didn't use it on the aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //method fills up the dropdownlist
        }
```

What happens is after the second postback I get the title error:

> CS0103: The name 'document' does not exist in the current context

So, I'm new in JS but no my first time with it.
But why it happens after the second postback? Then doesn't work either.
I need some advice, if you need more details tell me.
Thanks!

Comment: How & where is this code being injected into the code behind?

Comment: Hi @ScottMarcus I just updated.

Comment: That updated code is not the code-behind. The code-behind is the `.cs` or `.vb` file.

Comment: Exactly in which function?

Comment: What is the name of the file that the JavaScript is embedded into?

Comment: Filters0800.ascx.cs

Comment: Ok, but the second bunch of code you show (with the HTML in it) is not that file. Please show how the JavaScript is being sent down to the client from the code-behind. Are you using a scriptmanager?

Comment: Oh no, I'm sorry I'm not using ScriptManager on my pageload method. Should I?